# Sharing a folder through NFSv4 and Samba on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, samba, nfs, access-control-list, nfs4

I encountered problem with configure samba server above nfsv4.

I have 2 servers with Ubuntu 12.04 on both of them.

First server serve as NFSv4 storage, for VDI and user shares. File system is ext4. At that point all seems to be OK.

Second server serve as samba server and shares some folders from first one.

Anything is OK while I used POSIX permissions to the shared folders, but now I want to use ACL.

On server1 I enabled acl, on the second one I installed nfs4-acl-tools
nfs4_(get|set)facl works fine, I can manage access on server2 with that tools. And ACL works fine from shell.

BUT! It is impossible to access protected folder under windows PC. (on Linux PC I can access folder as I want). Get permissions from Windows clients also doesn't work.

There is my samba config:

```
[general]
    ...
    # Store DOS attributes in extended attributes (no mapping)
    map hidden           = no
    map system           = no
    map archive          = no
    map readonly         = no
    store dos attributes = yes

    # need for prevent locking files
    strict locking = no

[folder]
    comment = all
    path = /mnt/folder
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = no
    read only = no
    inherit acls = yes
    map acl inherit = yes
    nt acl support = yes
    ea support = yes
    vfs objects = acl_xattr
    acl check permissions = False
    nfs4:acedup = merge
    nfs4:chown = yes
    nfs4:mode = special
```

Here is ACL on test folder

```
    nfs4_getfacl test
    A::OWNER@:rwaDxtTcCy
    A::f.lastname@localdomain:rwaDxtcy
    A::GROUP@:rwaDtcy
    A::EVERYONE@:tcy

    ls -la | grep test
    drwxrwx--- 2 root       root 4096 Apr  2 09:34 test
```

f.lastname - is user that might enter directory

Can anybody help me with that? I've already play with params and have no success.

Thanks a lot!